# Labels overlap in box instead of wrapping in scrollview

Tags: python, kivy

I have a large amount of text to put on my screen in a scroll view and so I am string to make a scrollview that I add a gridlayout (or any layout) to filled with labels each with the text in them. My code is below:
KV:

```
ScrollView:
#The scrollview that the gridlayout filled with labels is added to.
            size_hint: 1, .8
            id: content_holder_kv
```

PY:

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
#The gridlayout that the labels will be added to and that will then be added to the scrollview.
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
for i in range(1141):
    temp = ("Long stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong string")
    line_of_text = Label(text=temp,text_size=(self.size))
    #This is the part ^ that I think is causing the issues. When I didnt have(text_size=(self.size)) the labels just went off the end of the screen. I have attempted adding text size as well as other attributes to try to get the wrapping behavior I need where the text label uses the entire width of the screen, is multiline, and doesnt overlap text with other labels in the scrollview but I have been unable to achieve this behavior.
    layout.add_widget(line_of_text)
self.content_holder_py.add_widget(layout)
```

Some things I dont think matter but might so I will mention are that my app has multiple screens in it and I am trying to split up the lines because I am trying to display a book chapter. line of text is a sentance/paragraph from the book that I need to wrap around without overlapping with the other text labels. Below is the picture of what this code produces (have tried other layout setting options and am not sure what I have messed up to cause this).
[image]

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, which of the 3 did I fail to provide? I copy and pasted the code so I figured it was verifiable (may not be in which case my apologies I posted before hopping off for the night in hopes someones would spot an obvious error), I thought it was complete in that it has all of the code that is involved in the issue (unless somehow having multiple screens causes an issue in which case I failed on that) and I tried to make it minimal by not including parts that I thought were unrelated to the problem. Thank you for your input and I will do my best to solve whichever of the issues it is

Comment: I have given making the issue more clear a try, please tell me if I have at all or how I can edit it to do so. Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you ask for a minimum, it means that you eliminate the other parts of the code that are irrelevant but that you can still execute the code, so it is verifiable and complete. Your code are pieces of code, maybe the error is there, maybe not, but it can be reproduced, then the minimum is too minimal, making it incomplete. :)

Comment: Ok, Next time I will include the frame code that makes it copy paste runnable. Many thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Label that can grow vertically but wraps the text at a certain width:

```
<CustomLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

To scroll a GridLayout on it’s X-axis/horizontally and Y-axis/vertically, set size_hint property to (None, None).

[ScrollView - ScrollEffect,](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) [scroll_type](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_type), [bar_width](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.bar_width), etc.

> By default, the ScrollView allows scrolling along both the X and Y axes. You can explicitly disable scrolling on an axis by setting the do_scroll_x or do_scroll_y properties to False.
>
> To scroll a GridLayout on it’s Y-axis/vertically, set the child’s
>   width to that of the ScrollView (size_hint_x=1), and set the
>   size_hint_y property to None:
>
> When scrolling would exceed the bounds of the ScrollView, it uses a ScrollEffect to handle the overscroll.
>
> [scroll_type](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_type)
>
> Sets the type of scrolling to use for the content of the scrollview.
>   Available options are: [‘content’], [‘bars’], [‘bars’, ‘content’]
>
> [‘bars’]  Content is scrolled by dragging or swiping the scoll bars.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    content_holder_py = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        temp = "Long stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong stringLong string"

        for i in range(1141):
            line_of_text = CustomLabel(text=temp)
            self.content_holder_py.add_widget(line_of_text)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy ScrollView of Labels Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<CustomLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    content_holder_py: content_holder_kv

    ScrollView:
        bar_width: 10
        bar_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
        bar_inactive_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
        effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        size_hint: (1, None)
        size: (Window.width, Window.height)

        GridLayout:
            id: content_holder_kv
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Scrolling Labels]

Comment: Thank you, your method fixed it perfectly : ) side note could I use a custom kivy object to make more complex objects? (EX: a bottom layout bar or something) I havent played with them but they seem extremely flexible/ useful from how you were using it.

Comment: Yes, you can add a bottom layout bar e.g. ActionBar wdiget or custom layout bar.